# SQL query duvida

Tags: sql

Galera , vi a  seguinte expressão em um video de sql:

```
(union select  1,2,3 )
```

O que significa ?

link video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0zAChmZIZU

Comment: Você pretende que as pessoas tenham que acompanhar o vídeo pra te responder? Seria mais legal se você deixasse a pergunta autoexplicativa e reproduzisse o exemplo todo aqui.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função do operador **UNION** é retornar os **RESULTADOS DISTINTOS** de 2 `SELECTS` ou mais ( para listar também os resultados repetidos é usado **UNION ALL** )

Um exemplo de uso seria listar todas as cidades de uma tabela **cliente** junto com as de uma tabela **fornecedor**

**Exemplo:**

```
 SELECT cidade FROM Cliente UNION SELECT cidade FROM Fornecedor
```

Se você tiver apenas 2 clientes , 1 morando em São Paulo e o outro no Rio de Janeiro , e apenas  1 Fornecedor , de São Paulo a query vai retornar:
 
**São Paulo** 
**Rio de janeiro**

Usando **UNION ALL** para os mesmos dados:

**Exemplo :**

```
 SELECT cidade FROM Cliente UNION ALL SELECT cidade FROM Fornecedor
```

Resultado:
 
**São Paulo** 
**São Paulo** 
**Rio de janeiro**

O [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0zAChmZIZU) é sobre `SQL INJECTION`

Aparece uma página que exibe 3 dados e o autor usa o **UNION** em uma query string para exibir 1 , 2 e 3 no lugar dos dados originais. Depois ele substitui o código pra roubar dados e credenciais.